# como remover httpredirect web.config

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis

Estou testando o redirecionamento em desenvolvimento, executando o site através do visual studio.
E para testar o redirecionamento adicionei o seguinte trecho de código no web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://site.com.br" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Funcionou, porém como estou em desenvolvimento ainda removi o trecho, para continuar os testes no localhost, sem redirecionar, mas dessa vez o redirecionamento permanece funcionando mesmo removendo o httpRedirect.

Alguém sabe como remover o httpRedirect do web.config, que surta efeito.

Comment: Pergunta estranha é só comentar isso no webconfig

Comment: Parece uma resposta obvia, mas não é, pois tentei comentar, remover, mas nenhum caso o efeito de redirecionamento parou, ficou permanente, paliativamente tive que recriar a solução, no visual studio em Arquivo>Abrir>Site e selecionar a pasta do site, mas isso cria uma nova solução, cada solução criada muda a porta localhost:xxxxx. Esse procedimento que fiz de recriar a solução resolve o problema mas vejo que não é a melhor forma.

Comment: Uma vez eu vi que ao rodar o site pelo visual studio, ele cria um web.config em outro diretorio mas não lembro onde que fica, talvez se localizar nesse outro talvez tenha vestigios desse trecho e posso tentar remover para solucionar o problema mais adequadamente. Se souberem o caminho que fica o site, ou web.config quando o visual studio esta rodando o site, já ajuda para essa tentativa.

Comment: Cara se está confundindo as bolas! o redirecionamento fica permanente,*** isso não é verdade***, é algo que está fazendo e fica difícil saber o que, em relação do Visual Studio ele cria uma porta para testar mas, o que tem a ver isso é normal isso

Comment: Esta achando que estou mentindo quanto ao redirecionamento, eu não teria feito a pergunta se estou com esse problema, oque estou fazendo? apenas coloquei o trecho mencionando na pergunta, e o redirecionamento funcionou, removi o mesmo trecho do web.config nada mais feito além disso, porém o redirecionamento não parou, ele continua redirecionando. Por favor não fique duvidando, estou com problema e é serio, você disse "isso não é verdade", é verdade sim, alguma falha provocou isso.

Comment: Olha sinceridade, não é nesse aspecto de mentir ou não, o que você fez no seu projeto para ficar redirecionando é no mínimo estranho, não é verdade no meu ver porque imagine você se você retirou o redirecionamento do arquivo `WebConfig` deveria não ter, talvez todavia não estou vendo seu projeto e você agora vem dizer falha? falha de quem do aspnet eu acho não provavel. Não foi ataque, não foi nenhum tipo de tirar onda, mas, isso não existe cara. Coloque mais parte do seu projeto, explique mais detalhado só isso fica impossivel responder.